# How to execute code after writing to csv without it being included in the csv

Tags: php

I'm writing to a CSV file using the following code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
$data = array(
        'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
        '123,456,789',
        '"aaa","bbb"'
);

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ( $data as $line ) {
    $val = explode(",", $line);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);


   echo "Do something else";
   exit();
```

I want to execute code after `fclose($fp);`. But in the above example `echo "Do something else";` is included in the CSV file. How can I ensure that any code after the fclose is not included in the outputted csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the code that you want to run after the csv file is generated in a seperate file and then call that file to run using fopen() after the csv has been created.

Answer (score 1):

You have included headers as content disposition. So you can NOT echo something. It will be always printed in the excel sheet.

However you can perform other tasks such as insert/update/select/delete in database and other things which does not print anything.

Comment: @user2721465 Why do you want to print anything after flushing excel file by the way?

Comment: In the real world scenario the php includes an html file after the csv is written to change the screen. Instead the html is outputted to the csv file

Comment: I guess you are showing an anchor link to the PHP file and disposing the content. In that case it will temporarily open a new tab and immediately flush that excel sheet and close that tab.